# how to automatically add a single blank row, after similar date entries in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am making an expense tracker. Suppose in this, I have purchased 5 things on 1 Aug 2021, 3 things on 2 Aug 2021, 4 things on 3 Aug 2021, and so forth. I am pushing the data through google forms and I want that upon entering the data for a particular date, google sheets must automatically analyze whether the entry is of the same date or different. If it is of a different date, then a blank row must be added between the two distinctive dates.

Mainly, I want to group the same date entries and all in all, make different date entries blocks just to keep the table neat.

I couldn't think of any way apart from manually entering a blank row. I am new to google sheets. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which type does your data belong to, destination of google form response, or table copied  from google form responses?

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: In google forms, the Purchase date is of date type and the purchase item is short text.

Comment: If you want the sheet to do something upon refresh, you will have to use Apps Script. In that case, I think you should start with Googling Apps Script and SpreadsheetApp. But do you really need to? What is the difference between creating blank rows between purchases of different dates vs coloring the cells differently, for example? What is the difference between outputting what you want on a different tab (so that you can use native formulas) vs editing the data in place? Your sheet may run faster with native formula/formatting and it can be much quicker to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify your source data (which is more advised), you can use a formula for that:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(
split(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,
   if(len(A2:A),
       {A2:B,if(A2:A<>A3:A,";;",";")
        },
)),";",true,false)),",",true,true)))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula is effective. Thanks, for it. But, I am populating the sheet through google forms. That means, data is getting updated (added) every day, externally. Also, the question header in google forms automatically links itself to the column headers in google sheets. I can't modify it. That is Purchase date in Column A is fixed by the question header in gforms. It can't be column D. This formula needs & creates a duplicate table with all the columns, taking values from the original columns. Isn't there a way to modify the original columns directly?

Comment: Usually if you give a sample to work on, the solution will be according to what we see, and then you may need to adapt it slightly. But if still it doesn't solve your problem, then you have to give a more explicit sample of data and expected outcomes to work on, which reflects the exact situation. (It does not mean that your provide your data, but you just replicate your situation AS IT IS with dummy data)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to keep formatting here is the simple solution:

```
function insert_white_rows_between_days() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).sort(1); // sort by first column
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // wait to update the spreadsheet

  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  var new_data = []

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    new_data.push(data[i]);

    try {
      // get string 'month + day' for current line and next line
      var d1 = data[i][0].getMonth() + data[i][0].getDate();
      var d2 = data[i + 1][0].getMonth() + data[i + 1][0].getDate();

      // if the strings are not equal add a black row between the lines
      if (d1 != d2) {
        new_data.push(['', '']);
        new_data.push(data[++i]);
      }
    } catch (e) { }

  }

  sh.getRange(2, 1, new_data.length, new_data[0].length).setValues(new_data);
}
```

It will work fine for a simply text table (with a header).

If you need to preserve the formatting it can be done this way:

```
function insert_white_rows_between_days_keep_formatting() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).sort(1); // sort by first column
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // wait to update the spreadsheet

  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  var tresholds = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
    var d1 = data[i][0].getMonth() + data[i][0].getDate();
    var d2 = data[i + 1][0].getMonth() + data[i + 1][0].getDate();
    if (d1 != d2) tresholds.push(i)
  }

  tresholds.reverse().forEach(r => sh.insertRowAfter(r+2));
}
```

It's even shorter and simpler as it turned out, but the method `insertRowAfter()` is not very efficient, it can be slow if you have hundreds rows to insert.

And implementation depends on what do you mean 'automatically'. This script can be fired via 'Run' button in Script editor of course. And you can add Custom menu on your sheet and click on it. If you want to run it really automatically you need to think how exactly it should work. It can be `onEdit()` or `onOpen()` events, or probably `onFormSubmit()` trigger, etc.

Comment: How to modify the script, if I have 7 columns of entries, with the date column being column B?

Comment: As for a number of columns I think it should work with any number. It just takes all of them on the sheet. As for dates in column 'B', it will need the minimal correction: `.sort(2)` instead of `.sort(1)` and `data[i][1]`, `data[i+1][1]...` instead of `data[i][0]`, `data[i+1][0]` respectively. [0] is a first column, [1] is a second column, etc,