# Trying to write a script to insert a line separating like data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script to insert a line that will separate data based on specific information.

This is what the spreadsheet looks like:

```
Date of the Game    Name    Section
02/25/2023  bob 1
02/25/2023  billy   2
03/04/2023 - CL beth    3
03/04/2023 - CL martha  4
```

I would like to script to change the spreadsheet to add a blank row between date groups:

```
Date of the Game    Name    Section
02/25/2023  bob 1
02/25/2023  billy   2
        
03/04/2023 - CL beth    3
03/04/2023 - CL martha  4
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to automatically add a single blank row, after similar date entries in google sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696648/how-to-automatically-add-a-single-blank-row-after-similar-date-entries-in-googl)